# Why is Jenkins not running the contents of this loop?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

So I have a `Jenkinsfile` like this:

```
properties([
  [$class:   'BuildDiscarderProperty',
   strategy: [$class:               'LogRotator',
              numToKeepStr:         '10',
              artifactNumToKeepStr: '15']]
])

List<String> buildFlavours = ['ubuntu', 'macosx']
List<BuildStep> modulesGroups = [
  new BuildStep('UnitTestGroup1'),
  new BuildStep('UnitTestGroup2')
]

println "*** outside loop, buildFlavours.size() = ${buildFlavours.size()}"
buildFlavours.each { flavour ->
  println "*** inside loop, flavour = ${flavour}"
  println "*** outside loop, modulesGroups.size() = ${modulesGroups.size()}"
  modulesGroups.each { group ->

    // Doesn't work, silently terminates the pipeline with no error!
    println "*** inside loop, group = ${group}"

    // Somehow this works:
    // String groupCopy = group.toString()
    // println "*** inside loop, group = ${groupCopy}"
  }
}

class BuildStep {
  private String displayName

  BuildStep(String displayName) {
    this.displayName = displayName
  }

  @Override
  String toString() {
    return displayName
  }
}
```

When I run it, I get the following output:

```
[Pipeline] properties
[Pipeline] echo
*** outside loop, buildFlavours.size() = 2
[Pipeline] echo
*** inside loop, flavour = ubuntu
[Pipeline] echo
*** outside loop, modulesGroups.size() = 2
[Pipeline] echo
*** inside loop, flavour = macosx
[Pipeline] echo
*** outside loop, modulesGroups.size() = 2
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
```

How is it that the contents of the loop don't seem to be executed, neither printing the message nor throwing an error?

The best lead I have is Jenkins is using that Groovy CPS thing, and maybe it might be screwing up rewriting the code for some reason.

**Investigation so far:**

1. It isn't throwing any kind of `Throwable` - if I try to catch one, nothing is caught.
2. When I change the println inside the loop to `toString()` the object first, somehow that *does* work and the message from inside the loop does get printed, but I haven't figured out why yet.
3. Making the `BuildStep` class Serializable or changing its name doesn't affect anything.
4. For now, [filed a ticket](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-57651) since at the very least I think the poor error reporting could be fixed.

Comment: what is it- BuildStep?

Comment: Best guess here is that the buffer is not being flushed after the implicit type conversion, but is after the explicit type conversion. Might as well just explicitly cast it since that seems to work.

Comment: @MattSchuchard the buffer flushing seemed like an interesting idea, so I looked at that, but actually, even in the output I can see that it does run the second loop. So it's almost like it's not running the body of the loop depending on the contents of the body of the loop, but that would be crazy, so I assume an error of some sort is happening and not being propagated...

Comment: @daggett `group` is a `BuildStep`, yes

Comment: What is the full class name?

Comment: @Trejkaz Then based on your experimenting I think you figured it out yourself: explicitly cast the object as a String since something seems to error without a message otherwise.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Actually casting as a string doesn't work either, it seems like the workaround has to be actually calling toString(). So the question was about why, rather than how to work around it.

Comment: @daggett the full classname is just `BuildStep`. I'm not even sure you can put package names on classes defined in Jenkinsfile itself.

Comment: Something wrong  in this class. I believe if you replace it with string everything would be fine. Where you declared it? What's inside? ...

Comment: @daggett it's in the question above, at the bottom of Jenkinsfile. There really isn't all that much to the class, but the reason it's there is that the real version also carries a bunch of extra information which was too complex to jam into a single string.

Comment: Sorry, missed it. Could you try `inplements Serializable` to class definition and rename it to smth like MyBuildStep

Comment: @daggett same result. I've also tried adding an asString() method in case Groovy was trying to call that first.